# regex get chess pgn sub variations

Tags: regex, chess

i want get between "(" and ")" symbols with regex.

```
[Date "????.??.??"]
[Result "*"]
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]

1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 Nc6 ( 2...d6 3.d4 ( 3.c3 Nc6 4.d4 ) ) ( 2...e6 3.d4 d5 ) 
*
```

**it's a short example, can be longer**

but like that

```
( 2...d6 3.d4 ( 3.c3 Nc6 4.d4 ) )
( 2...e6 3.d4 d5 )
```

rexeg patterns generally returns `

```
( 2...d6 3.d4 ( 3.c3 Nc6 4.d4 ) ) ( 2...e6 3.d4 d5 )
```

because of finding last ")"

i have no idea how writing regex pattern which making this work. is there anyone who can help me

Comment: cascading can create issue in regex

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a recursive regex pattern , so that it would check for the balancing of brackets.

```
\((?:(?R)|[^()])*\)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yD2cY0/2)